# System.Windows.Forms objects disable AzureRM cmdlets

Tags: .net, powershell

I have a Powershell script on which I am putting a form. The script is interacting with Azure through the `AzureRM` module, using commands like `Get-AzureRMVM`. I then use `System.Windows.Forms.Form` objects to communicate with a a user. For example

```
Import-Module AzureRM
Connect-AzureRMAccount
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Script:GUI = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
#GUI size etc.
Get-AzureRmVm
```

This is not a full example, but I have found that simply the `New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form` completely stops `Get-AzureRmVm` from ever returning a value. If I comment out the `New-Object` line everything works normally.

Comment: Do you get a error when you run this? you should get one for Console-WriteLine is not a command. You should use write-host.

Comment: Ooh oops yep, that's true but that's just me rewriting by accident. I'm actually just calling `Get-AzureRMVM` in my script just to see if it returns at all, edited to change command

Comment: so now that it is changed. Do you get a error? or does aything display when you click the button>

Comment: Absolutely nothing. Even without the `[system.windows.forms.application]::run($Script:GUI)` and just running `Get-AzureRMVM` doesn't actually ever return. Running it always returns up until a `New-Object System.Windows.Forms.anything` call like in the variable inits. No errors are thrown

Comment: So just want to double check if you run `Get-AzureRMVM` alone it works. But once you call `New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form` it stops working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own issue, `AzureRM` is now partially out of support/development so moving to the new module just called `Az` has all the same functionality with out the crazy glitches like this one.